# 68000 - What do the values in the US and SS signify? (Stacks)

Tags: 68000

Currently the value in US is  "00FF0000" and the value in SS is "01000000". Are these where the pointers are? Or are they what is stored? Im a bit confused.

Comment: @JasonBaker: Probably the User Stack Pointer and the Supervisor Stack Pointer. USP and SSP would've been clearer.

Comment: Sorry guys, i have made the title clearer. I dont want to know what is stands form but what the values in them are.

Answer (score 1):

The values of the `ssp` and `usp` registers are the actual stack pointers. There's no additional indirection, i.e. they are not addresses of addresses. They are pointers into the supervisor (`ssp`) and user (`usp`) stacks.